# In Bootstrap, why my search button is not inline?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following code to make a simple formular with bootstrap:

```
<form class="form-inline">

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">De</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">A</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Départ</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Retour</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label"></label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">recherche</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

But the result is:

[image: this]

So, why is the search button above the other input fields ? Is there a way to recenter it without touching the responsiveness ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see snippet below .

first, your `input` fields were exceding the `width` of the `col` . so set `max-width:100%` to them

second, `.btn` has `inline-block` style , use `display:block` instead

let me know if it works for you

```css
input { 
  max-width:100%
}
.form-group .btn {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">De</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">A</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Départ</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Retour</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label"></label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">recherche</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: its bad practice to make btn block globally

Comment: @eirenaios then don't do it globally. make it only for this specific btn. it's not hard to use proper css selectors to do so

Comment: if by adding &nbsp; solves the issue why bother much, see m y answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43630059/3540289

Comment: oh. so that's why you downvote my answer ? so that your answer gets accepted ? my answer is just another solution. don't be bitter. plus, your answer does not align the button with the other inputs.

Comment: I ve downvotes your answer because if this works and he accepts and other millions of user sets display block in their css the whole things gets messy.

Comment: Its doesn't align with other input is because the code itself is at it is that is another issue to be resolved, i just answered the question what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Add an empty label with `&nbsp;` on top of the button to align, like this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<form class="form-inline">
    
      <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
          <label for="name" class="control-label">De</label>
          <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
          <label for="name" class="control-label">A</label>
          <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
          <label for="name" class="control-label">Départ</label>
          <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
      </div>
    
      <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
          <label for="name" class="control-label">Retour</label>
          <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
      </div>
    
      <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
          <label for="name" class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">recherche</button>
      </div>
    
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button should not be in a form group, and additionally that's not the usual way to markup an inline form (using cols). See this example where I use some of your fields for brevity:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<form class="form-inline">

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">De</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">A</label>
      <input type="email" value='' id="name" placeholder="Ime">
  </div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">recherche</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an <br/> after label , like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">De</label><br />
      <input type="email" value='' id="name1" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">A</label><br />
      <input type="email" value='' id="name2" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Départ</label><br />
      <input type="email" value='' id="name3" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Retour</label><br />
      <input type="email" value='' id="name4" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
      <label for="name" class="control-label"></label><br />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">recherche</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding form-label and control-label classes with non-breakable space worked for me

```
<label for="name" class="form-label control-label">&nbsp;</label>
```